# Pyinstaller : --noconsole gives error and doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have been trying different solutions from all over the internet and still haven't found a solution that works for me yet.

this is the pyinstaller command i use

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import "numpy.core._dtype_ctypes" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats.dbc" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats.arxml" --hidden-import "asammdf.blocks.cutils" --additional-hooks-dir=hooks --onefile --noconsole myscript.py
```

my python script uses few cmd commands as well **but redirecting the output doesn't work**

```
my code -- 

    import eel
    from pathlib import Path
    from asammdf import MDF
    from pathlib import Path
    import glob
    import sys
    import os
    from datetime import timedelta
    import subprocess
    
    eel.init("D:\SharedFolder\suprava\VS code\Python")
    @eel.expose
    def pythoncode():
        #python code ----
        #few cmd commands but redirecting the std 
        output doesnt work

eel.start("main.html")
```

The `.exe` seems to work well without the `--noconsole` option but i dont wish to show the code's std output in the terminal.

i tried editing the `service.py` file as well, as suggested by other solutions on the internet, but that doesn't seem to work as well.

**Is there a way to hide the terminal after the .exe file has been created?**

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: yes. i am @Alexander `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write`

Answer (score 3):

When you use `--noconsole` mode it sets your `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to None automatically, so if your code or the libraries it uses logs or writes messages to either of those streams it will cause an error.  Usually something like `NoneType object has no attribute write`.  If this is the error you are receiving then all you need to do is redirect `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to a new stream like an open file or an io buffer.  For Example:

```
import io
import sys

stream = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = stream
sys.stderr = stream
```

Just have your script run that code as early in your script as possible.

Comment: Thankyou so much! works well. But, when i press a button in my GUI that triggers a particular function, the terminal opens up for a second. is there a way to hide that? @Alexander